# Problem converting nvarchar to decimal t-sql

Tags: t-sql, casting

I'm trying to convert `nvarchar` to `decimal (18,2)` and I'm receiving the following message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

The CAST is: `CAST(bm_onnet AS decimal(18,2)) as bm_onnet_corr`, 
it works only if the value has only maximum 3 decimals, doesn't work for value below:

```
21.8333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

How should I modify my SELECT?

Answer (score 7):

Use the round function

example

```
declare @v nvarchar(100) = '21.8333333333333333333333333333333333333'

select convert(decimal(18,2),round(@v,2))
```

a select would look like this

```
SELECT CAST(round(bm_onnet,2) AS decimal(18,2)) as bm_onnet_corr
```

Comment: this would work in an sql program, I just needed an answer for a simple select, thanks anyway!

Comment: +1. `CAST(CAST(bm_onnet AS float) AS decimal(18, 2))` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
        case when charindex('.',bm_onnet)) > = 2 then 
          convert(decimal(18,2),substring(bm_onnet,0,charindex('.',bm_onnet)+3))
        else 
          convert(decimal(18,2),bm_onnet)
        end
```

too early in the morning use this instead.

Comment: I should have popped open sql server it could have saved me a lot of headaches.